# SQL return distinct rows based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query. Yes, I know, I didn't post the schema, but all the joins are fine and I don't think it is relevant.

How do I return all rows for a distinct `counties.name` and `cities.states_id`.

I've worked with distinct before but never with two columns.

Thank you

```
SELECT c.name AS id, CONCAT(c.name,", ",ci.states_id) AS value
FROM counties AS c
INNER JOIN zipcodes AS z ON z.counties_id=c.id
INNER JOIN cities_has_zipcodes AS chz ON chz.zipcodes_id=z.id
INNER JOIN cities AS ci ON ci.id=chz.cities_id
WHERE c.name LIKE "San Fr"
ORDER BY id LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function and a `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT c.name AS id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name, ', ', ci.states_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS value
FROM counties AS c
INNER JOIN zipcodes AS z ON z.counties_id=c.id
INNER JOIN cities_has_zipcodes AS chz ON chz.zipcodes_id=z.id
INNER JOIN cities AS ci ON ci.id=chz.cities_id
WHERE c.name LIKE "San Fr"
GROUP BY c.name, ci.states_id
ORDER BY id LIMIT 100
```

Comment: As a note, you can do:  `GROUP_CONCAT(c.name, ', ', ci.states_id SEPARATOR ', ')`.  The nested `concat()` is not necessary.